# Concatenate list of strings into single string

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I am new in flutter I want to know how can i concatenate the list of strings into a single string.
I tried to do phrase.toString(). i have also tried

But I am not getting the required result. How can I get the concatenation of only tags of the list? Any help will be appreciated.

```
List phrase = [
      {
        'tag': 'This is a flutter',
       
      },
      {
        'tag': 'learning session',
        'icon': icon.flutter,
      },
      {
        'tag': 'Therefore,',
        'icon': icon.learningHat,
      },
      {
        'tag': 'Login here',
      },
    ];
```

I am expecting the out should be: This is a flutter learning session. Therefore login here.

I have tried:

```
final phraseTags = phrase[index]['tags'];
```

but not getting the required result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method:

```
getTags(List list) {
 List listOfTagsOnly = list.map((e) => e["tag"].trim()).toList();
  return listOfTagsOnly.join(" ");
}

print(getTags(phrase)); // This is a flutter learning session Therefore, Login here
```

Comment: Thanks @Gwhyyy ..it works. How can i add extra characters if i wanted to add some commas or fullstops in that?

Comment: you mean if you want to separate them with special characters ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gwhyy. Yes, i want to add 'comma' and 'and' keyword before the last string. for example, i have four strings and i have joined them into one and i am getting one, two,three,four. is it possible that i can get one, two, three and four can i add 'and' keyword before the last string?

Answer (score 1):

You are having typo on `tags` will be `tag`

```dart
final phraseTags = phrase[index]['tag'];
```

Comment: thanks for your response. yes i have use tag but the problem is i am getting empty space between each tag like : This is a flutter  ( empty space)     learning session (empty space) Therefore (empty space ) and so on... its doesnt look like a complete sentence

Comment: Can you include how you are using it on widget

Comment: i am using listview builder which returns a row that has children, a text widget for tag, and an icon widget for icons. i just want to concatenate the tags only is there any way to do so? so that i can bind that variable in my text widget

Comment: Can you include that part, also an image that you like to archive

Comment: if you like to get on single string you can do `final result = phrase.map((e) => e["tag"]).join(" ");`

Also for space `.trim()` will help

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for how can I add extra characters like commas and also i want to get only one sentence but i am getting 4 same sentences

Comment: can you  include desire output. it will be easy for me to get the question

Comment: thanks for your response i fixed it. just need one more suggestion from you that I am joining the string separated by a comma, is it possible that i can use 'and' before the last string? for example, i have four strings and i have joined them into one and i am getting one, two,three,four. is it possible that i can get one, two, three and four can i add 'and' keyword before the last string?

Comment: looping/map will be easy